# Finding similar values in two lists using the filter function

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a function called **sqPyramidVolume** that takes in two parameters that are lists: **baseHeightList** and **volumeList**.

**baseHeightList** is a list of tuples that contain the base and the height.

I use the map function to calculate the volume which creates a list that I set as 'volume'. Once it determines whether one value is in both lists, it's placed in a 'correctLIst'. The correctList is then returned.

**My issue:**

I want to use the filter function to look at the volumeList and volume to see if they have similar values. I know I can use something like, 'correctList = [c for c in volumeList if c in volume]' but I'd like to use filter if possible.

This is my code so far:

```
baseHeightList = [(1,3),(3,4)]
volumeList = [13,1,12,9,4,2]

def sqPyramidVolume(baseHeightList,volumeList):
    volume = map(lambda x: int((x[0]**2 * x[1])/3),baseHeightList)
    for n in volumeList:
        correctList = filter(lambda x: x[n] == volume[n],volumeList)
    return correctList

sqPyramidVolume(baseHeightList,volumeList)
```

The return value should be [1,12]. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use `sets` to check for inclusion instead of the `filter` built-in function. Nonetheless, I have included the correct filter function here.

```
baseHeightList = [(1,3),(3,4)]
volumeList = [13,1,12,9,4,2]

def sqPyramidVolume(baseHeightList,volumeList):
    volume = map(lambda x: int((x[0]**2 * x[1])/3),baseHeightList)
    return filter(lambda x: x in volume, volumeList)

sqPyramidVolume(baseHeightList,volumeList)
```